# Possible to use inheritance in TestNG test suits?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

Let's say I have the following TestNG test class:

```
public class OwnTestLauncher  {
    @Test(dataProvider = "valid-provider")
    public void validSintax(Collection<File> files) throws PlooException {
        runFilesThroughCompiler(files);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "invalid-provider")
    public void invalidSintax(Collection<File> files) throws PlooException {
        runFilesThroughCompiler(files);
    }

        protected String someAlgoritmUsedByRunFilesThroughCompiler(...) { ... }

        ...
}
```

And I'd like to then create some slightly different suits, so I can run each one of them on different ocasions:

```
public class SomeOtherFlavour extends OwnTestLauncher {
    @Override
    protected String someAlgoritmUsedByRunFilesThroughCompiler(files) { ... }
}
```

I've tried run the code shown above but it didn't work. I've also tried to annotate `SomeOtherFlavour` with `@Test` but that didn't seem to help. Is it possible, at all, to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This should definitely work: if you tell TestNG to run SomeOtherFlavour, it should see your two test methods. Are you seeing something different? Even further: you can put a @Test on the OwnTestLauncher class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to extract the `someAlgoritmUsedByRunFilesThroughCompiler` into a separate interface (or abstract class), and write different implementation classes of it.

```
public interface MyAlgorithm {
    String someAlgoritmUsedByRunFilesThroughCompiler(...);
}
```

The test methods in `OwnTestLauncher` then expect an implementation of this interface as an additional parameter, and you can still use your data providers by adapting them.